# Random Zsh Prompt

Tags: shell, command, line, zsh

I'm using a custom Zsh prompt (no OhMyZsh or anything like that). What I'd like to do is basically build a few different Zsh prompts and have them randomly change every-time I load a new shell (similar to the way that the `fortune` app works. In case it's relevant, my Zsh prompt look like this:

```
PROMPT='%F{blue}%1~%f %F{cyan}%f '
RPROMPT=\$vcs_info_msg_0_
```

It's just a really simple prompt that displays current location with some customized color, and a right prompt that displays what branch I'm on, when in a git repo.

Comment: I hope that you don't want to shuffle together random characters for getting some different prompt everytime, but like `fortune`, you have a set of predefined prompts, and want to pick one of them at random. In this case, you could store all possible prompts into an array and pick one array element at random for setting your prompt. For added thrill, you could use variables for the colours in the prompt, and set the variables to a random value too.

Comment: zsh ships with a simple password theme manager with a random option - try: `autoload -Uz promptinit; promptinit` and then `prompt random` to change the prompt. You can add your own themes (see the `zshcontrib` man page), but it doesn't have a standard way to limit the random choices, so it will pick from everything listed by `prompt -l`. To restrict the set, you could hack it a bit, and override the internal array used by the code, e.g.: `prompt_themes=(pws redhat zefram newtheme1 newtheme2)`